# Is it possible to use SAML for the WebClient of Dynamics NAV 2017?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

My Company is using Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2017 and is preparing to switch to BC in a few years (what ever that means). For now we still want to put in some work in Nav2017. Here I was asked to setup the WebClient and use SAML for authentication.
I successfully created an IIS and worked out the delegation to the testserver. I could connect to the Webclient when using User and Password. But my company wants me to use SSO, SAML if possible.
We are using an Azure AD App Proxy and there you have the possibility to use SAML for localy used Apps. But well for that I would need the entitiy-ID, which means I would have to setup the NAV-Server first to be able to use SAML.
So how do I do that? Any documentation or anything at all? Anyone ever done this? Is that even possible in the first place? If its not possible to use SAML, what about other SSO methods?
And before you ask, yes we have backups and yes, tested them already and they work. I am using a testserver with testinstances, neither the productive server nor the productive instance to play around.

searching for SAML SSO in combination with NAV2017 but no results. Only saw some sort of ms365 authentication but didnt read a lot about that, because my focus for now was on SAML.

Comment: It seems like everything you need to configure is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/authenticating-users-with-azure-active-directory

Comment: after I tried to force the command in the NAV Administration shell to use WebAuth (how ever the full statement was that I found) I got an Error stating that WebAuth is not supported by the NAV Server. So I assumed that SAML is simply not possible with NAV 2017 and I will use instead what you posted. Thanks

Comment: Good luck. Btw, there are zero reasons to stick to nav 2017. You should just upgrade to BC (it is just newer version of Nav). At least upgrade to BC 14 should be relatively simple. For later versions it becomes much more complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Help with third-party services, as well as topics related to software within a user's corporation, are generally [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like everything you need to configure is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/authenticating-users-with-azure-active-directory).